# tor alternative

Tags: proxy, internet, privacy, tor

I am using TOR as an proxy for some scripts I'm running (nothing illegal just don't want to expose my IP address) but I'll randomly get network timeouts which don't happen when I run the scripts directly.  I have 2 questions -

1) Is there a way to get a more reliable connection using tor? I know its a free anonymous proxying tool so beggers can't be choosers but from my experience it doesn't seem very reliable.

2) If there is no way to check if your connection is good then is there an alternative to tor? Hopefully free, but I'm willing to pay for reliability (hopefully not too much).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good tutorial available at http://www.howtoforge.com/ultimate-security-proxy-with-tor on how to use a squid proxy server on one of your local systems to balance multipliable tor connections.

I have used this setup and found that it dramatically increased the reliability and performance of tor.

Also if you only want to hide your ip address you may want to check if your ISP runs any caching proxy's, Obviously this would provide a lot less privacy that what you would get from tor (e.g: if the isp is presented with a court order they will hand over your details) but if you are just looking for a way to protect your computer from attacks from unscrupulous websites this will give you a reliable alternative with very little stress.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a VPN service. Here some links : http://techpp.com/2009/07/09/top-5-free-vpn-clients/